# Exact timing in Java game loop

Tags: java, network-programming, timing, game-loop

I'm developing a network based game, and I'm now focusing on the server side simulation. Of course I need a game loop, and I opted for a fixed timestep loop so that it will be far easier to reproduce on the client(s) than a variable timestep one. I also decided to run my game at 60 Hz. This is the game logic speed, not rendering speed. Rendering will be handled with a variable timestep loop in the clients to have the best possible rendering.
The server is written in Java.

I already made an example game loop using code from http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0 and modifying the loop with my code. Here is the loop:

```
private void gameLoop()
{
  final double GAME_HERTZ = 60.0;
  final double TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000000000 / GAME_HERTZ;
  //We will need the last update time.
  double lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
  //Store the last time we rendered.
  double lastRenderTime = System.nanoTime();

  int lastSecondTime = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);

  long extraSleepTime = 0;
  while (running)
  {
     int updateCount = 0;

     if (!paused)
     {
        long loopStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        updateGame();
        updateCount++;
        long timeAfterUpdate = System.nanoTime();
        lastUpdateTime = timeAfterUpdate;

        //Render. To do so, we need to calculate interpolation for a smooth render.
        float interpolation = Math.min(1.0f, (float) ((loopStartTime - lastUpdateTime) / TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES) );
        drawGame(interpolation);
        lastRenderTime = loopStartTime;

        //Update the frames we got.
        int thisSecond = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);
        if (thisSecond > lastSecondTime)
        {
            long nanoTime = System.nanoTime();
           System.out.println("NEW SECOND " + thisSecond + " " + frameCount + ": " + (nanoTime - lastNanoTime));
           lastNanoTime = nanoTime;
           fps = frameCount;
           frameCount = 0;
           lastSecondTime = thisSecond;
        }

        long loopExecutionTime = timeAfterUpdate - loopStartTime;
        long sleepTime = (long)TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES - loopExecutionTime - extraSleepTime;
        // Only sleep for positive intervals
        if(sleepTime >= 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime / 1000000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("WARN: sleepTime < 0");
        }
        // Counts the extra time that elapsed
        extraSleepTime = System.nanoTime() - timeAfterUpdate - sleepTime;
     }
  }
```

The problem is that, when running, the FPS aren't stable at 60Hz, but sometimes go lower. For example I sometimes get 58-59Hz, going as low as 57Hz.
This variability wouldn't be a problem if the game was run locally, but as our game is networked, I need to keep the exact time so that I can reproduce the logic calculations on both client and server.

Is there any error in this code, or anything that could be improved to make it more stable? Our goal is 60Hz being kept exactly all the time.

EDIT: A first solution that came up in my mind is running the loop a bit faster than it needs to, for example at 70Hz, and checking the frame count to limit the updates to 60 per seconds. This way the simulation would be run in bursts and would need buffering, (up to 60 frames at a time), but should be able to never be slower than needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve 60 frames per second, you'd be better off using a scheduled executor as `Thread.sleep()` may not be as precise as you'd like it to be. Consider the following sample for your server code: (Please note it contains Java 8 code)

```
    public void gameLoop() {
       // game logic here
    }

    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
             .scheduleAtFixedRate(this::gameLoop, 0, 16, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

It will run your `gameLoop()` every 16 milliseconds which is essentially what you want. This should give you much more precise results. You can also replace 16 and `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` with their nanoseconds counterpart, even though it shouldn't make any noticeable difference

Comment: With this the loop would run a bit faster though as 1000 / 60 is 16,666..., not just 16. With the code I posted in the question I think it would adapt as needed to adjust the delay (e.g. doing a few frames at 16 ms and a few at 17 ms), doesn't it?

Comment: Yes you are right on both occasions. However, in practice it is highly likely that a scheduled executor will be more "stable", whereas Thread.sleep might have different results. On the same matter you could make the executor a bit more precise with having 16666(6)... and change TimeUnit to nanoseconds.

Comment: In any case both methods should do the job and shouldn't bother you. I'd say complete the boilerplate of the game first and give it a go. In practice you will not see the difference between server running at 57 or 60 fps.